# Loop through rails associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

1)I'm trying to create a site that has several restaurants each having their own unique menu being displayed in a table, the association works in the console but not in code.I loop over the @restaurant instance variable then in the table I put the data I want from the menu so restaurant.menu.dish but getting an error that 'each' is undefined even though I didn't state a one-one relationship.How may I carry out the desired behavior?

2) How do I ensure that the menu data corresponds with the right restaurant,I'm assuming that the show controller saves the restaurant variable with a specific ID and calling a method like .dish would know what restaurant based on the show action variable, is this correct thinking?

Restaurant Model

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :thumbnail, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :thumbnail, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  has_many :menus

  def self.search(search)
    if search
    @restaurants= Restaurant.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
    else
      @restaurants=Restaurant.all
    end  
  end
end
```

Menu Model

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

Restaurant controller with show action

```
def show
  @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
end
```

Show.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <h3>Menu</h3>
    <thead><tr><th>Dish</th><th>Price</th><th>Calories</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <%= @restaurant.each do |restaurant| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= restaurant.menu.dish %></td>
            <td><%= restaurant.menu.price %></td>
            <td><%= restaurant.menu.price %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to change parameter name in method `search` to something like `query_string`. It is ambiguous in db query.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing *restaurant*, that has *many menus*, right? Here we go:

```
<%= @restaurant.menus.each do |menu| %>
  <tr>
     <td><%= menu.dish %></td>
     <td><%= menu.price %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Of course it would be that simple! Thanks, will keep this in mind.